# How do I remove some of the bones from the World of Warcraft model?

Tags: xna

The wow model viewer exports the model with 150 bones, and XNA SkinnedEffect supports a maximum of 72 bones. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The XNA reach profile (which is why SkinnedEffect has those limitations) isn't meant for hi-def games. You will have to use the XNA full profile and write your own vertex and fragment shaders that support 150 bones. What platform are you targeting, BTW?